# How to understand "s.words.length – (s.downcase.words – desired_words).length" in text processing?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm reading beginning  ruby -petter cooper and i have been stucking at this part for hours :

```
hot_words = %w{test ruby}
 my_string = "This is a test. Dull sentence here. Ruby is great. So is cake."
       my_string.sentences.find_all do |s|
         s.downcase.words.any? { |word| hot_words.include?(word) }
       end

def self.best_sentence(sentences, desired_words)
  ranked_sentences = sentences.sort_by do |s|
    s.words.length – (s.downcase.words – desired_words).length
  end
  ranked_sentences.last
end
```

The method above is trying to pick out the most important sentences by processing  how many words difference each sentence has from the desired words list. What confuses me the most  is 
`s.words.length – (s.downcase.words – desired_words).length`

Does '`s.words.length`' means each sentence's length ?  if so what about "`s.downcase.words.length`" ?  Why don't they just process each sentence's desired_words length and rank the longest one.  Those thoughts  have been running through my head, but i know it must be  something really simple, but i just can't get through .

Your help will be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Depends on the definition of `String#words`, which is not part of Ruby’s core but used here.

Comment: "How to understand this or that" - What I would do is stop execution in that area in the debugger and then step through the code, evaluating different expressions and seeing what they return. Or, if I'm feeling particularly lazy, insert a bunch of `puts` statements with different expressions and then look at the log.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out Andrew Marshall , I have include the missing part . And also , Great suggestions  . Sergio  Tulentsev. I think that's probably the best way to understand each fragment.

Comment: @Snailwalker: expanded as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a technique I use most every day. It's called "debug printing". It consists of decorating your code with a bunch of print statements, which output different values that you're interested in. In this concrete example, you might want to output these:

```
def self.best_sentence(sentences, desired_words)
  ranked_sentences = sentences.sort_by do |s|
    puts "analyzing string: #{s}"
    puts "words: #{s.words}"
    puts "downcased words: #{s.downcase.words}"
    puts "desired words: #{desired_words}"
    puts "without desired words: #{s.downcase.words - desired_words}"
    s.words.length – (s.downcase.words – desired_words).length
  end
  ranked_sentences.last
end
```

Then you just run the code and look at the console or the log (whereever the stdout goes)

Comment: Thank you so much. This would make my life much easier ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through it in detail. But first, let me write the method substituting `split` for `words`, since the `String` class does not have a method `words`:

```
def best_sentence(sentences, desired_words)
  ranked_sentences = sentences.sort_by do |s|
    s.split.length - (s.downcase.split - desired_words).length
  end
  ranked_sentences.last
end
```

I also removed `self.`, which has no effect when `self=>main`.

Next we need some data:

```
desired_words = %w{ winter best hope age despair season light spring}

sentences = [
  "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times.",
  "It was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness.",
  "It was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity.",
  "It was the season of light, it was the season of darkness.",
  "It was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair."
]
```

First, to simply, I will remove the punctuation from `sentences`:

```
sentences.map! { |s| s.tr(',.','') }
sentences
  #=> ["It was the best of times it was the worst of times",
  #    ...
  #    "It was the spring of hope it was the winter of despair"]
```

The method begins `sentences.sort_by`, which returns an enumerator:

```
enum = sentences.sort_by
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["It was the best...winter of despair"]:sort_by>
```

(It's all there, I've just used `...` to save space.)

The method [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) calls upon [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) to pass the elements into the block, one at a time, and assign them to the block variable `s`.

You don't believe me?

```
def best_sentence(sentences, desired_words)
  enum = sentences.sort_by
  enum.each do |s|
    s.split.length - (s.downcase.split - desired_words).length
  end
  ranked_sentences.last
end

best_sentence(sentences, desired_words)
  #=> "It was the spring of hope it was the winter of despair"
```

We can use [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to obtain each element of `enum`:

```
s = enum.next
  #=> "It was the best of times it was the worst of times"
```

and we now perform the calculations in the block for this sentence:

```
a = s.split
  #=> ["It", "was", "the", "best", "of", "times",
  #    "it", "was", "the", "worst", "of", "times"] 
b = a.length #=> 12 
c = s.downcase.split
  #=> ["it", "was", "the", "best", "of", "times",
  #    "it", "was", "the", "worst", "of", "times"] 
d = desired_words
  #=> ["winter", "best", "hope", "age", "despair",
  #    "season", "light", "spring"] 
e = c - d
  #=> ["it", "was", "the", "of", "times",
  #    "it", "was", "the", "worst", "of", "times"] 
f = e.length
  #=> 11 
d = b - f
  #=> 1
```

As this sentence has only one of the desired words, `sort_by` uses `1` in the sort for this sentence. Let's now pass the second sentence into the block:

```
s = enum.next
  #=> "It was the age of wisdom it was the age of foolishness" 
a = s.split
  #=> ["It", "was", "the", "age", "of", "wisdom",
  #    "it", "was", "the", "age", "of", "foolishness"] 
b = a.length
  #=> 12 
c = s.downcase.split
  #=> ["it", "was", "the", "age", "of", "wisdom",
  #    "it", "was", "the", "age", "of", "foolishness"] 
e = c - desired_words
  #=> ["it", "was", "the", "of", "wisdom", "it", 
  #    "was", "the", "of", "foolishness"] 
f = e.length
  #=> 10 
d = b - f
  #=> 2
```

Similarly, for the remaining three sentences we obtain:

```
d = b - f # "It was the epoch of belief..."
  #=> 0 
d = b - f # "It was the season of light..."
  #=> 3 
d = b - f # "It was the spring of hope..."
  #=> 4
```

Therefore, `sort_by` sorts on the sentences by the respective computed values:

```
[1,2,0,3,4]
```

Therefore,

```
ranked_sentences = [
  "It was the epoch of belief it was the epoch of incredulity", #0
  "It was the best of times it was the worst of times",         #1 
  "It was the age of wisdom it was the age of foolishness",     #2
  "It was the season of light it was the season of darkness",   #3
  "It was the spring of hope it was the winter of despair"]     #4
```

Lastly, the method returns:

```
ranked_sentences.last
 => "It was the spring of hope it was the winter of despair"
```

Comment: Hey Cary, Thank you so much for your writing. I will look though it. You must spent much time on it. I really appreciate it !

Comment: I have just finished reading it. it makes perfect sense now ! thank you so much !